# Unable to see computers on site to site VPN

Tags: windows, linux-networking, site-to-site-vpn, troubleshooting

Windows server: 192.168.0.10
Linux server: 192.168.0.1
Network printer: 192.168.0.30

192.168.0.0/24  site to site with 192.168.1.0/24

On a computer on second subnet (192.168.1.32) I can ping the Linux server & the network printer, even remote desktop to a 192.168.0.xx computers but can not ping any computer on the 192.168.0.xx network or connect to the server shared drive.

What does an Xerox network printer & Linux server have to be seen but not Windows 10?

I am trying to connect the 192.168.1.x computer to the server as the end result.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Windows firewall blocks ping by default unless you have applied a group policy or local setting to allow ping

Comment: but how about the drive mappings?  

Start > Run > \\server 

I can't find the server from any of the 3 computers on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. But the Linux (Samba) server is totally open for drive mappings.  

I know I am missing something simple and can't remember what it is.

Comment: There is a build in firewall rule for File and Printer Sharing you can enable to allow that traffic

Comment: I have turned off the Windows Defender firewall just to make sure it wasn't the problem. My Win 10 build allows "ping" naturally to all other computers.

Comment: Windows blocks incoming pings, outgoing is allowed by default